# Need counterexample for some facts related with Quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> If $N$ is the maximum number of consecutive quadratic non residues  modulo an odd prime $p$ then $N < \sqrt p$
>
> If $n$ is the least positive quadratic non residue an odd prime $p$ then $n < 1+ \sqrt p$

I think that both the facts are not true. I tried with some small numbers but in those classes it turned out that the facts are true. Any idea to prove or construct counterexamples?

Comment: Why do you think that there is a counterexample ?

Comment: @Peter: Just the intuition,nothing much. Are the results true?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124688/213622

Comment: According to my calculations, the second claim is true for the odd primes upto $10^9$ . I do not think that there is a counter-example.

Comment: For the first claim, it might help that the perfect squares are in particular quadratic residues modulo $p$ restricting the non-reidues already, perhaps even enough to show the claim, but I am not sure.