# Sum of quadratic residues in $[1,p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the sum of all quadratic residues modulo $p$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30785/find-the-sum-of-all-quadratic-residues-modulo-p-where-p-equiv-1-pmod4)

Show that if $p$ is a prime of the form $4k + 1$, the sum of quadratic residues ($\bmod p$) in the interval $[1, p)$ is $\frac{p (p - 1)}{4}$.

My attempt :

I could prove that the sum of the quadratic residues $\bmod p$ is $\frac{k ( 2k + 1 ) ( 4k + 1 )}{3} \bmod p$ (where $p = 4k + 1$). $p$ already divides this.

So, the sum of quadratic residues is a multiple of $p$.

What else can I try ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit ! I'll be more careful in future.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate. I guess I should do a thorough search before posting. Can a moderator please close this ?

Comment: Don't worry, @Jatin. Though a thorough search is always advisable, sometimes not even veterans can find stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Quadratic_Residues_of_a_Prime), the number of quadratic residue of an odd prime is $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Now, if $x$ is a quadratic residue of $mod\ p$ , so is $p-x$ as $-1$ is a quadratic residue of any prime $≡1\pmod 4$.

Using [Legendre Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html), $(\frac{-x}{p})=(\frac{-1}{p})(\frac{x}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(\frac{x}{p})=(\frac{x}{p})$ if $p≡1\pmod 4$.

So, we can always find an integer $p-x<p$ for each and every  quadratic residue of  $x<p$, so that their sum is $p$.

And $x≢p-x$ if $p$ is odd.

Clearly, there are in-congruent $\frac{p-1}{4}$ pairs if $4\mid(p-1)$ each pair having sum$=p$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks !